# Why does MSVC give me 'wrong' results?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm expecting to `addr addr 33 44` where addr can be anything and both be the same.

In gcc [I get that](http://ideone.com/0nuEEx). But in MSVC I get

```
8D3678 0 9257096 9257096
8D3678 0 9257104 9257104
8D3678 0 9257112 9257112
```

WTF!?! I get no warnings/errors. Does anyone care to explain why the last two values are not 33 44 and why they are the same (and very wrong).

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
class Person{
public:
    int age;
    int weight;
    Person(int age, int weight):age(age), weight(weight){}
};
int main() {
    std::vector<Person> ls;
    Person p(33, 44);
    ls.push_back(p);
    ls.push_back(p);
    ls.push_back(p);
    for(auto i=ls.begin();i!=ls.end();++i){
        printf("%X %X %d %d\n", i, &(*i), (*i).age, (*i).weight);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with std iterators, but isn't the proper form `i->age` or something like that?

Comment: Passing an iterator to `printf` is undefined behavior, though I'm not certain how it arrived at that output even so.

Comment: Why are you using `printf` and not `std::cout`?  Seems to me that `printf`'s `va_arg` could be not be consuming the right amount of data from the argument list.  At least explicitly cast the arguments to `printf` first to give it the types that correspond to your format specifiers.

Comment: @MooingDuck: oh right, I thought I was passing the iterator pointer. Oops. It must be 8+bytes which explains why the parameters on the right side are being ignored (too much data on stack)

Comment: @jamesdlin: Habit. Its much easier to say show me hex address with printf and I had << " " << in std:cout which i would have to write 3 times here so hell no. I'll be happy when MSVC implements printf with variadic templates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are passing a `vector::iterator` as a `printf` argument, where an integer is expected. This gives undefined behaviour. (Incidentally, so does passing a pointer as the second argument; but this is likely to give the result you expect on a 32-bit platform). `printf` is not type-checked, which is why you should usually use C++-style I/O instead.

GCC's implementation is just a wrapper around a pointer, so you accidentally get the result you expect; MSVC's implementation seems to be a larger type - certainly, in a debug build, iterators are quite large on that platform in order to support run-time validity checks.

> I get no warnings/errors

That's because you didn't enable them. On gcc, with `-Wall` (or just `-Wformat`), I get:

```
test.cpp:16:72: warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Person*, std::vector<Person> >’ [-Wformat]
test.cpp:16:72: warning: format ‘%X’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘Person*’ [-Wformat]
```

telling me exactly what's wrong.

Comment: I believe in MSVC if you crank the warnings up to 4 it will also warn about this

Answer (score 7):

Iterators (including `std::vector<Person>::iterator`, which you are passing as an argument to `printf()`) are **not** guaranteed to be PODs, and arguments to a C-style variadic function can only be PODs.

> WTF!?! I get no warnings/errors

That is because passing non-POD arguments to a C-style variadic function is  **undefined behavior**. The compiler is not required to issue a diagnostic, although some very nice compilers do that ([as correctly mentioned by Mark B in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154025/why-does-msvc-give-me-wrong-results/17154110#comment24831603_17154110)).

Comment: g++ will even helpfully warn if you try to pass a non-POD to `...` in a function call.

Comment: while it's correct that iterators are not guaranteed to be non-PODs, I think you meant to say that they're not guaranteed to be PODs.

Comment: @MarkB: OK, thank your for pointing that out, I added it to the answer

Comment: @MooingDuck: Right, I had a different sentence in my mind :) Thank you for correcting me

Answer (score 1):

You use `"%X"` format specifier to format an iterator. "Unsmart" the iterator using `&*`.

In gcc a vector's iterator is normally a wrapper over a pointer and has the same size and layout. This is why you can pass an iterator to `printf` and get away with that.

In MSVC in debug mode debug iterators are used which contain more members than one pointer and they don't have the same size and layout. This is why your code breaks with MSVC in debug mode.